# JPQL Coalesce non-scalars?

Tags: sql, jpa, hql, jpql

I have a table storing application configuration parameters like so:

```
 setName | key        | value
----------------------------------
 dev     | FooEnabled | true
 dev     | BarEnabled | true
 qa      | FooEnabled | false
 ...etc...
```

Each parameter, a key/value combination, belongs to a particular "configuration set." It's easy to select all properties in a particular set:

```
SELECT p Parameter p WHERE p.setName = :name
```

So if I wanted all the parameters in config set named `"dev"` I'd get back

```
 dev | FooEnabled | true
 dev | BarEnabled | true
```

Now I'd like to select the union of two sets:

```
SELECT p Parameter p WHERE p.setName = :name1 OR p.setName = :name2
```

...but eliminate rows with duplicate keys by giving properties in set with `name1` higher precedence than properties in set with `name2`. If `name1` was `"qa"` and `name2` was `"dev"`, then this would return

```
 dev | FooEnabled | true
 qa  | BarEnabled | false
```

To clarify, the query should SELECT:

- Every property from set with name `name2`, except when...
- There is a property with the same key in set with name `name1`, in which case...
- Select the row with `setName = :name1` instead of the row with `setName = :name2`

---

**What JPQL query will do this efficiently?** If `COALESCE` worked with non-scalar values, then I imagine that something like this could work:

```
SELECT
    COALESCE(x, y)
    FROM Property x, Property y
    WHERE
        x.setName = :name1 AND
        y.setName = :name2 AND
        x.key = y.key
```

but `COALESCE` only accepts scalar values. Any ideas?

---

Other queries attempted/failed:

```
SELECT
    CASE
        WHEN (NOT EXISTS (SELECT y FROM Property y WHERE y.setName = :name1 AND y.key = x.key))
        THEN x
        ELSE y
    END
    FROM Property x
    WHERE
        x.setName = :name2
```

---

I'm also interested in selecting individual rows in the same manner, by `key`, which I suppose would look like the following (if only COALESCE worked for non-scalars):

```
SELECT
    COALESCE(y, x)
    FROM Property x, Property y
    WHERE
        x.key = :key AND
        x.setName = :name1 AND
        y.key = :key AND
        y.setName = :name2
```

Answer (score 0):

Possibly you can create a query with basically following structure:

```
SELECT
  Property p,
  CASE WHEN setName=:name1 
       THEN 1
       ELSE 0
  as orderColumn
FROM Property x
WHERE x.setName = :name1 OR (x.setName =:name2 AND (NOT EXISTS (SELECT y FROM Property y WHERE y.setName = :name1 AND y.key = x.key)))
ORDER BY orderColumn
```

(Just from my mind without having it tried)

Comment: I'm playing around with this now, but I don't see the point of the `orderColumn` ordering...

Comment: @Matt Ball I interpretated your sentence 'by giving properties in set with name1 higher precedence than properties in set with name2' in such a way, that you wanna have elements within the set of matchings by name1 at top and every matching by name2 at bottom...Maybe thats wrong...